# Counting rotational symmetries of cube.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Question**: I am counting rotational symmetries of cube. Here in the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/531090/168676 i didn't get the third point in the hint that is "Consider the permutations of your named vertices when the cube is rotated about each of six axes which penetrate the midpoints of opposite edges. There are 6 of such permutations.

**Please explain above point. I not getting which axes are mentioned in this point. I attached a figure and draw the axes which penetrate the midpoint of opposite edges. Is it correct? Please check**?

[image: here is the image]

Further, what are angles of rotation about the axes which are mentioned in above point.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you’ve correctly drawn two of these six axes. You can draw two more by connecting the remaining dots in your image. You haven’t drawn dots for the midpoints of the vertical edges yet; if you do that, you can draw two more axes, for a total of $6$. Each of these rotations needs to map the edges that it intersects to themselves, so the rotations have to be through an angle of $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your answer. Sir, if i represent each of the vertices by numbers $1,2,...,8$ resp. and represent all these motions by permutations then is it subgroup of $S_8$ (symmetric group on 8 symbols) ? Further is this subgroup is isomorphic to $S_4$ ? How to prove that...

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: It is indeed a subgroup of $S_8$. You can prove that it's isomorphic to $S_4$ by considering how it permutes the $4$ long diagonals that connect opposite vertices.