# How many rotations are there in $\mathbb R^3$ which take $C$ to itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $C$ denotes the cube $[-1,1]^3\subset\mathbb R^3.$ How many rotations are there in $\mathbb R^3$ which take $C$ to itself?

A. $6$

B. $12$

C. $18$

D. $24$

Comment: TIFR ? :D what are your thoughts?

Comment: Please add your approach to the problem and we will be glad to provide hints.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326625/automorphism-group-and-congruences-of-the-cube/326680#326680
Also maybe this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry

Answer (score 4):

Let $H$ be the set of vertices of the cube, i.e. $H=\{1,2,\cdots,8\}$. Label the vertices of the cube $H$ such that $1$ is adjacent to $2$ and so forth. Consider the rigid motions (that is rotations) of vertex $1$.

There are how many different vertices to which $1$ can be sent, not including the motion which fixes the cube?

> There are $7$.

So including the one that fixes the cube, there are .... total. Then there are how many possibilities for the placement of vertex $2$ as it must be adjacent to vertex $1$.

> There are $3$.

This yields a total of how many total possible rigid motions of the cube?

> $3\cdot 8=24$ total ways.

Since a rigid motion must fix the edge connecting vertex $1$ and vertex $2$, this is sufficient to determine the cube. Hence, there are .... total rigid motions (rotations) which fix the cube.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I have adjusted my answer to be a more 'appropriate' hint. Think about each step carefully.

Comment: yes yes.. I would try.. Thank you :)

Comment: Will you please say why fixing $1$ and $2$ fixes the whole cube